# FOS elastica bundle 4.* - automatic index entity does not work

Tags: symfony, elastica, foselasticabundle

I'm currently trying to let the FOS Elastica bundle to automatically update the index when there are new entries with the following settings:

```
fos_elastica:
clients:
    default: { host: localhost, port: 9200 }
indexes:
    audit:
        finder: ~
        types:
            audit_log:
                persistence:
                    driver: orm
                    model: AuditBundle\Entity\AuditLog
                    # Problem occurs here. This should trigger automatic inserts, updates and deletes
                    listener: ~
                    provider: ~
                    finder: ~
                    model_to_elastica_transformer:
                        service: app.audit_transformer
```

However, my custom model to elastica transformer isn't triggered. Anyone any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case I had an event subscriber which injected rows into a SQLite database without the Entity Manager. This lead to a situation in which the event listener of the FOSElastica bundle didn't detect changes. In order to index these rows into ElasticSearch I extended the subscriber with:

```
public function __construct(
    TokenStorage $securityTokenStorage,
    EntityManager $entityManager,
    // These lines
    ObjectPersisterInterface $postPersister,
    IndexableInterface $indexable,
    array $config
){
    $this->securityTokenStorage = $securityTokenStorage;
    $this->audit = $entityManager;

    // These lines
    $this->objectPersister = $postPersister;
    $this->indexable = $indexable;
    $this->config = $config;

    parent::__construct($postPersister, $indexable, $config);
}

public function onFlush(...)
{
    // ....
    //* Insert audit in ElasticSearch
    $audit = $this->audit->getRepository('AuditBundle:AuditLog')->findLast();

    if ($this->objectPersister->handlesObject($audit)) {
        if ($this->isObjectIndexable($audit)) {
            $this->objectPersister->insertOne($audit);
        }
    }
    // ....
}

/**
 * @param object $object
 * @return bool
 */
private function isObjectIndexable($object)
{
    return $this->indexable->isObjectIndexable(
        self::AUDIT_INDEX,
        self::AUDIT_TYPE_NAME,
        $object
    );
}
```